# Reasons for usual restrictions on trigonometric functions to have inverses

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Since the trigonometric functions are not injective, we have to restrict their domain. Why do we choose the usual intervals, i.e., $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ for sine, $]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$ and $[0,\pi]$ for cosine? We could just have added $\pi$ to all and got other intervals where they are injective...

Is it because we want to have $sin(arccos(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $cos(arcsin(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, etc?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course, the choice is arbitary, but natural. Moreover, the relation you mentioned is another good reason. Sometimes other "branches" are considered, but I do not think this gives any additional insight. One might argue that the interval $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ is more natural, but we would lose the nice property $f(-x)=-f(x)$, which is another good reason. In the case of the cosine, nothing is more natural than choosing $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: @Peter yes, but if we were to do $tan(arccos(x))$ or $tan(arcsin(x))$, then the expressions would not be defined in all the values in the restrictions... $x$ couldn't be $0,-1,1$